# How can I pass parameters to --output in youtube-dl?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

Have a csv file with a bunch of youtube links. 
It's structured like `video-name \t part \t youtube-url`

i want to use youtube-dl with python to download each video and have it be saved as `video-name_part.extension` - is it possible to do this or can I only do things like %(name)s that are included in youtube-dl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the `youtube_dl` module and then pass the parameters using a parameter dictionary. You would need to take a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L117-L265) for finer control on what you can do, but `outtmpl` allows you to control the output format in the way you suggested.

The following script shows you how you could go about reading your CSV file:

```
import csv, youtube_dl

with open("filelist.csv", "r") as f_filelist:
    csv_filelist = csv.reader(f_filelist, delimiter="\t")

    for cols in csv_filelist:
        video_name = cols[0]
        part = cols[1]
        youtube_url = cols[2]

        ydl_opts = {"outtmpl" : r"{}_{}.%(ext)s".format(video_name, part)}

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([youtube_url])
```

Comment: thanks much. i figured it would be using format, but i just wasnt sure how to structure it in the `outtmpl`. my alternative was to just save it as `%(id)s.%(ext)s` and then rename/move the file to my output directory as desired.